# Get the values of maps in arrayList

Tags: groovy, gsp

I have an arrayList of maps that i generate in my controller and pass to GSP page!

i would like to get the values of the maps as a list to present in g:select in gsp!

as in each element (Map) in the arrayList! The select option value should be the map value and the map key as an optionKey 
as i want to use this key in a script when the user choose an option!

sorry am a bit confused if the question is not quite clear!

```
 ArrayList[Map1,Map2,Map3]
    Map1[1,value1]
    Map2[2,value2]
    Map3[3,value3]
    // the values are strings to show in select
   //the respective key of the option value the user has chosen i want it as option key so i can pass it to script
```

Comment: Could you make your example code something people could use rather than pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have a list (ArrayList) of Maps and you want to represent each map as a select, right?

Your arraylist of maps could be something like this:

```
def words_en = ['One':'Apple', 'Two':'Pear', 'Three': 'Strawberry']
def words_it = ['One':'Mela', 'Two':'Pera', 'Three': 'Fragola']
def words_de = ['One':'Apfel', 'Two':'Birne', 'Three': 'Erdbeere']

def myList = [words_en, words_it, words_de]
```

you can generate the select elements as follows:

```
<g:each var="myMap" in="${myList}" status="i">
    <g:select id="select_${i}" name="select_${i}" optionKey="key" from="${myMap}" optionValue="value" ></g:select> <br/>
</g:each>
```

EDIT:
With the edited version of your question I understood that you have several maps each containing only one key-value pair. Given that your keys are unique, the best approach is to merge all your maps into one and simply use that to populate the select:

```
def words_1 = ['One':'Apple']
def words_2 = ['Two':'Pera']
def words_3 = ['Three': 'Erdbeere']

def myList = [words_1, words_2, words_3]

def myMap = [:]
myList1.each{map->
    myMap.putAll(map)
}
```

and in the view:

```
<g:select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" optionKey="key" from="${myMap}" optionValue="value" ></g:select>
```

Comment: Thanks can u check the code sample i just edited ! maybe i couldn't explain my problem clearly first